# Using conditional variables to unblock one thread but wouldn't mutex lock cause a deadlock?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

Basic question but for the sake of briefness, I have two threads where `bar` unblocks `foo` upon a certain condition, but even though the program runs fine to my surprise, shouldn't it cause deadlock if `foo` is run first which acquires the lock which means `bar` shouldn't be able to proceed further given the condition variable would never be true in `foo`?

```c
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cv;
bool dataReady = false;

void foo(void *arg)
{
    printf ("Foo...\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    
    while (!dataReady)
    {   
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);
    }
    printf ("Foo unlocked...\n");
    dataReady = true;
    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void bar(void *arg)
{
   printf ("Bar...\n");
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
   sleep(3);
   printf ("Data ready...\n");
   dataReady = true;
   pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);
   
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main(void)
{

int main() 
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,foo,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,bar,NULL);
    
    
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Also in this context, using semaphore wouldn't make sense yes?

Comment: "if foo is run first" I'm not convinced that your code can guarantee that `foo` will be the first to acquire the lock.

Comment: there's an "if". I never talked about guarantee, and OS doesn't guarantee either. I said it *could* occur first

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);` atomically releases the mutex when called and the re-acquires it when woken up.

From [man 3 pthread_cond_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait):

> These functions atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread
> to block on the condition variable cond; atomically here means
> "atomically with respect to access by another thread to the mutex and
> then the condition variable". That is, if another thread is able to
> acquire the mutex after the about-to-block thread has released it,
> then a subsequent call to pthread_cond_broadcast() or
> pthread_cond_signal() in that thread shall behave as if it were issued
> after the about-to-block thread has blocked.
>
> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be
> owned by the calling thread.

IMHO C++ documentation contains clearer explanation (I know the languages differ, but the principle of operation remains the same):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

> 1. acquire a std::unique_lockstd::mutex, on the same mutex as used to protect the shared variable
> 2. either
>
>    1. check the condition, in case it was already updated and notified
>    2. execute wait, wait_for, or wait_until. The wait operations atomically release the mutex and suspend the execution of the thread.
>    3. When the condition variable is notified, a timeout expires, or a spurious wakeup occurs, the thread is awakened, and the mutex is
>       atomically reacquired. The thread should then check the condition and
>       resume waiting if the wake up was spurious.

Comment: Right on, so basically if the condition is false, the thread execution is blocked/suspended until it's signalled from elsewhere which in this case is `bar`, and while it's suspended, the mutex is no longer acquired by it

Comment: @xyf basically: yes.

Comment: thanks. A follow up: semaphore wouldn't make sense in this case since that'd cause a deadlock in case `foo` is run first?

Comment: @xyf A mutex is a semaphore with count of 1. So you are technically using a semaphore. The main use case for count of more than 1 is for resources that CAN be used in parallel but needs to limit the number of parallel users (examples of such resource is the number of sockets opened at once - eg. by default it's around 1000 on Linux an around 200 on MacOS). For such cases you use a semaphore to let N number of processes acquire the lock in parallel but the N+1 process will be blocked until one of the N processes free the lock.

Comment: @xyf your program looks like a simple "producer-consumer" pattern, so the classical solution is either the one you have presented or the one with two semaphores: see [Little book of semaphores](https://greenteapress.com/wp/semaphores/). I can't think of any solution utilizing a single semaphore only at the moment.

Comment: @slebetman I was thinking between conditional variables and semaphores to begin with. If I have multiple threads that `ThreadA` is interfacing with via message queue, and it needs to wake up certain threads as long as there's something relevant to that thread in the message queue, it shall be able to wake up that thread by setting a conditional variable. With semaphores, if you just have one `sem_t sem` object, you can't invoke`sem_post` on it to unblock one specific thread. That's just my understanding

Comment: @xyf For message queues the best design pattern IMHO is to use a pipe. That way you can use I/O events to pause threads when reading empty queue (they get blocked) and wake up threads when there is a message. However doing this for multiple consumer threads gets complicated. For such use case I'd use a proper message queue like RabbitMQ, MQTT, ZeroMQ etc. as they allow the programming model to be simple again just like using pipes.

Comment: Aren’t message queues different than pipes though? Perhaps we are mixing the terms. I’m referring to posix message queues. You could still block the thread via mq_read() until it’s populated via mq_send(). In my case tho, message queue contains data of multiple threads and each thread needs to be woken up accordingly to empty the queue

Comment: In which case wouldn't the message queue wake up your thread? You don't need to manually wake up the consumer threads. If mq_read() is atomic then there's nothing more you need to do. If not then you can protect the message queue with a mutex on the consumer side (the producer don't need to use the mutex - hence avoiding deadlocks, the reason the producer don't need a mutex is that the queue itself will block the consumer until the producer writes something to the queue)